# 1946 Horehound Beer recipe - what is "capaicine"?

Tags: herbs, beer

I was researching [Horehound Beer recipes](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/117369671) on (the old newspaper website) Trove.  I found the name of an ingredient - perhaps a herb, that I did not know: "Capaicine".

As best as I can read, this recipe is:

> HOREHOUND BEER
>
> Ingredients are: 4-lb. [horehound herb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrubium_vulgare),
> 18-lb. sugar, 1½-lb. licorice extract, 1½-lb.
> treacle, 4-oz. [quassia chips](https://www.herbcottage.com.au/dried-quassia-chips.html), 10-oz. crushed
> ginger, 2-oz. coriander seeds, 2-oz. capaicine,
> 4-oz. caramel, 2-oz. tartaric acid,
> ¼-pint brewer's yeast. Suspend the horehound,
> ginger, coriander and quassia in
> a muslin bag in a copper and boil in
> about 15 gallons of water for half-an-hour,
> Add sugar and than other ingredients.
> Strain off into fermenting vat,
> Strain sufficient water through herbs to
> bring up to 24-gallons. When at 80-deg. F.
> break up yeast in a basin of brew and
> stir into the bulk. Allow to ferment for
> about 24 hours, skim off top and filter.
> Fine down with one pint ale finings.

NOTE: Australia used imperial measurements until 1966.

As stated, I am unable to identify the ingredient "capaicine".  I don't think it's misspelling of "[capsaicin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicin)".  I wondered for a while if it was maybe a misspelling of "[cinnamonmum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamomum)", but have since given up on this idea.

I could of course, be reading the old newsprint incorrectly.

NOTE: This particular beverage *must* be delicious, since it is to be made in ~100 litre batches.

Bonus question: Is the "caramel" referred to, a browned sugar-syrup (perhaps made from condensed milk) or a colourant?  A lot of recipes add "burnt sugar" for colour.

Comment: I think you've misread the spelling... that looks like "cap**s**icine", not "capaicine". (Of course, that would still make it a typo.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect that the word intended was "capsicum". 2 ounces of chili pepper would be reasonable given the amounts of other spices. 2 ounces of capsaicin would be difficult to source and would make the beer essentially inedible.

Comment: Possibly French origin based on some search results I can see.

Answer (score 7):

I would vote for a spelling error, and that capaicine is actually capsaicin.  I can't find any reference for the original spelling.  I have never consumed horehound beer, but it seems to me that, in looking at the ingredients, a little spice-heat would make sense. Think of the spiciness you get in the back of your throat when drinking ginger ale.  I would say caramel is a color additive.  It is not uncommon for sodas to have caramel color added.  I'm no expert on 1940's beverages, so I would be happy to be corrected.

Edit:  Thanks, @Sneftel....Your reasoning is more sound than mine...I would also go with "capsicum", as opposed to "capsaicin" (upvoted!).  This also aligns with the comment below about a reference to chili peppers, though I have not specifically come across that.

In the end, if you interested in recreating this recipe, I bet you could zero in on the level of spiciness by experimenting with chili flakes.  Maybe not 2 ounces at once, but a little at a time until the desired effect was achieved.

Comment: While your reasoning is sound, I'm wondering if capsaicin would be a readily-available ingredient in 1946?  (EDIT: found and advertisement for capsaicin capsules from 1867).

Comment: 2 ounces of capsaicin in 24 gallons of water would make pepper spray, not beer.

Comment: capaicin is an old way to refer to chili peppers, particularly cayenne. It is NOT the active ingredient capsaicin. (Google thinks the same way and *always* go "did you mean...")

Comment: I definitely agree with using chili flakes. You'll get more consistent control of heat level than with fresh peppers, which vary between producers and throughout the year.